# JavaScript regex multiline text between two tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a regex to fetch string from HTML, but it seems the multiline flag doesn't work.

This is my pattern and I want to get the text in `h1` tag.

```
var pattern= /<div class="box-content-5">.*<h1>([^<]+?)<\/h1>/mi
m = html.search(pattern);
return m[1];
```

I created a string to test it. When the string contains "\n", the result is always null. If I removed all the "\n"s, it gave me the right result, no matter with or without the `/m` flag.

What's wrong with my regex?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML, HTML is NOT a regular language.  Use a HTML parser, resp. the DOM.  That is also much simpler.

Comment: You're looking for DOTALL, not multiline.

Comment: Note that JavaScript [will soon have](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/07/upcoming-regexp-features) the `dotAll` modifier so you can do `/.../s` and your dots will also match new lines. As of July 2017 it's behind a flag in Chrome.

Comment: @Svante "Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML": this is not parsing. Let us not to learn Chinese just for finding a '鱼'.

Comment: You can call it like you want, but the _actual_ question seems to be “how do I find the h1 headline in the div box-content-6?” while this regex (when it works) seems rather like “give me the last h1 headline that appears after the start tag of the div box-content-6” and even fails at that e. g. when there are matching parts that are commented out.  With a parser, you just parse, then query, which, depending on the language, might be e. g. just a css selector ".box-content-5 h1".  This is simpler, much more correct, and obviously so.

Comment: Use this for html parsing:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10585079/2571422

Answer (score 642, accepted):

You are looking for the `/.../s` modifier, also known as the *dotall* modifier. It forces the dot `.` to also match newlines, which it *does not do* by default.

The bad news is that it <s>does not exist in JavaScript</s> *(it does as of ES2018, see below)*. The good news is that you can work around it by using a character class (e.g. `\s`) and its negation (`\S`) together, like this:

```
[\s\S]
```

So in your case the regex would become:

```
/<div class="box-content-5">[\s\S]*<h1>([^<]+?)<\/h1>/i
```

---

As of ES2018, JavaScript supports the `s` (dotAll) flag, so in a modern environment your regular expression could be as you wrote it, but with an `s` flag at the end (rather than `m`; `m` changes how `^` and `$` work, not `.`):

```
/<div class="box-content-5">.*<h1>([^<]+?)<\/h1>/is
```

Comment: Damn! And what's the logic behind `[\s\S]*` ?!?!

Comment: @simo Match any whitespace or non whitespace character, effectively matching any character. It's like `.`, but matching whitespace too (`\s`) means it matches `\n` (which `.` doesn't do in JavaScript, or can be made to do with the `s` flag).

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Modifiers".

Comment: According to MDN, `[^]` also works to match any character, including newlines, in JavaScript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes

Comment: For performance issues, it is highly recommended to use the `*?` quantifier instead of `*` in order to avoid greediness. This will avoid catching the **last** <h1> of the document: that's probably not what you want and that's not efficient as the regexp will continue to look for <h1> until the end of the string even if it has already found it before.

Comment: The [^] version is way easier on the regexp compiler, and also more terse.

Comment: `[^]` works only in JavaScript (and other ECMAScript implementations), and can give wildly unexpected results if you try to use it in other flavors.

Comment: I am using ([\\S\\s]*?) regex in Nodejs but it's not working with $1 string.

Comment: If you are on webpack: take a look at https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-dotall-regex

Answer (score 21):

You want the `s` (dotall) modifier, which apparently doesn't exist in Javascript - you can replace `.` with [\s\S] as suggested by @molf.
The `m` (multiline) modifier makes ^ and $ match lines rather than the whole string.

Comment: You might add that the /s" modifier sets singleline mode as opposed to multiline mode. +1

Comment: Nine years later, JavaScript now has the `s` flag (ES2018). :-)

Comment: Can I use:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_dotall
MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/dotAll

Answer (score 13):

`[\s\S]` did not work for me in nodejs 6.11.3.  Based on the [RegExp documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), it says to use `[^]` which does work for me.

> (The dot, the decimal point) matches any single character except line
>   terminators: \n, \r, \u2028 or \u2029.
>
> Inside a character set, the dot loses its special meaning and matches
>   a literal dot.
>
> Note that the m multiline flag doesn't change the dot behavior. So to
>   match a pattern across multiple lines, the character set [^] can be
>   used (if you don't mean an old version of IE, of course), it will
>   match any character including newlines.

For example:

`/This is on line 1[^]*?This is on line 3/m`

where the *? is the non-greedy grab of 0 or more occurrences of [^].

Comment: For those who wonder what `[^]` means: it is like a double negation: *"match any character that is **not** in this **empty** list"* and so it comes down to saying *"match any character"*.

Answer (score 9):

The dotall modifier has actually made it into JavaScript in June 2018, that is ECMAScript 2018.
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-dotall-flag

```
const re = /foo.bar/s; // Or, `const re = new RegExp('foo.bar', 's');`.
re.test('foo\nbar');
// → true
re.dotAll
// → true
re.flags
// → 's'
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that it's better to split the multiple-line string with "\n" and concatenate the splits of the original string and becomes a single line and easy to manipulate.

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="Body" rows="12" data-rule="required" 
                  title='@("Your feedback ".Label())'
                  placeholder='@("Your Feedback here!".Label())' data-val-required='@("Feedback is required".Label())'
                  pattern="^[0-9a-zA-Z ,;/?.\s_-]{3,600}$" data-val="true" required></textarea>


$( document ).ready( function() {
  var errorMessage = "Please match the requested format.";
  var firstVisit = false;

  $( this ).find( "textarea" ).on( "input change propertychange", function() {

    var pattern = $(this).attr( "pattern" );
    var element = $( this );

    if(typeof pattern !== typeof undefined && pattern !== false)
    {
      var ptr = pattern.replace(/^\^|\$$/g, '');
      var patternRegex = new RegExp('^' + pattern.replace(/^\^|\$$/g, '') + '$', 'gm');     

      var ks = "";
      $.each($( this ).val().split("\n"), function( index, value ){
        console.log(index + "-" + value);
        ks += " " + value;
      });      
      //console.log(ks);

      hasError = !ks.match( patternRegex );
      //debugger;

      if ( typeof this.setCustomValidity === "function") 
      {
        this.setCustomValidity( hasError ? errorMessage : "" );
      } 
      else 
      {
        $( this ).toggleClass( "invalid", !!hasError );
        $( this ).toggleClass( "valid", !hasError );

        if ( hasError ) 
        {
          $( this ).attr( "title", errorMessage );
        } 
        else
        {
          $( this ).removeAttr( "title" );
        }
      }
    }

  });
});
```