# jQuery regex over multiple lines

Tags: jquery, regex, line-breaks

I have the following string:

```
<img alt="over 40 world famous brandedWATCHES BRANDs to choose from
" src="http://www.fastblings.com/images/logo.jpg"></strong></a><br>
```

I want to define a regex pattern like `<img alt="(.+?)" src="http://(.+?).(jpg|gif)">`, but as you can see the target string has a linebreak in the alt attribute - so how can i incorporate this? the rule should be like "anything in the alt-attribute including linebreaks".

Comment: **DO NOT PARSE HTML USING Regular Expressions**!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Ah, the `question` tag.  In case we get some questions that aren't questions...

Comment: The answer you selected is in fact incorrect. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

By default, the `.` wildcard operator does *not* match newline characters (`\n`, `\r`).  In other languages, there is a `DOTALL` mode (sometimes called single line mode) to make `.` match anything. Javascript doesn't have it for some reason. If you want the equivalent use `[\s\S]`, which means any character is white space or is not white space so:

```
/<img alt="([\s\S]+?)" src="http:\/\/(.+?)\.(jpg|gif)">/
```

See [Javascript regex multiline flag doesn’t work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068280/javascript-regex-multiline-flag-doesnt-work).

Also I escaped the `.` before `jpg|gif` otherwise it'll match any character and not the `.` that you intend.

That being said, parsing HTML with regexes is a really bad idea. What's more, unless there is relevant detail missing from your question, you can do this *easily* with [jQuery attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

```
$("img[src='http://.*\.gif|jpg']").each(function() {
  var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
  var src = $(this).attr("src");
  ...
});
```

Or if you want there to be an `alt` attribute:

```
$("img[alt][src='http://.*\.gif|jpg']").each(function() {
  var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
  var src = $(this).attr("src");
  ...
});
```

Comment: Deleted my comment as I thought it works nevertheless as the accepted answer uses the same approach. Anyway good to hear that I didn't miss some obvious point ;) Btw +1 from me.