# String extraction with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery and have an entire html page stored in `var page`

```
var page = '<html>...<div id="start">......</div><!-- start -->....</html>';
```

How can I extract only the section that starts with `<div id="start">` all the way to after the end tag `</div><!-- start -->` such that my output is

```
<div id="start">......</div><!-- start -->
```

Comment: You should [definitely](http://goo.gl/JnoOO) use regex for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(page).find('#start').html();
```

Comment: This would get the inner HTML, and not necessarily matching the original string.

Comment: Correct. I wondered whether to write this, too, but he wrote that he is using jQuery (wants to use?) and so this is the only way. If he ever needs the whole element (the outerHTML), he will find a way to wrap it. But what for?

Comment: Be VERY careful throwing `$(page)` around like that...  You'll want to save a "copy" of that if you plan on searching within it very often.  `var $page = $(page);`  Otherwise you're going to create/destroy multiple copies of the DOM representation...  Also, if you want to work with it in jQuery, you won't need the `.html()` -- i.e. `$page.find("#start").appendTo("#target");`

Answer (score 2):

if it's valid html, it would be easiest to just let the browser do it for you. Something like this would do the trick:

```
var page = '<html><head><title>foo</title><body><div id="stuff"><div id="start">blah<span>fff</span></div></div></body></head></html>';

var start_div = $('#start', page).parent();
alert( start_div.html() )
```

You can see this example in action [at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wS3Cm/).

[edit] as @Nick pointed out above, this would probably not include the html comment at the end of the div.  It also might not work in all browsers -- I don't know -- you should test it.  Post back and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

```
var start = page.match(/(<div id="start">.*?<!-- start -->)/m)[1];
```

Comment: This won't work if there is a newline between the opening and closing tags.

Comment: @Ender: Of course, forgot to add the "m" for multi-line mode.

Comment: In any case, chances are the OP did not want what he asked for. A regex will return exactly what he asked for, but if what he really wants is an html component rather than that exact string, he should be using jQuery html parsing like many others here have suggested.

Comment: Unfortunately, JS doesn't have that feature (or rather, it does, but not in the way you're thinking).  Multi-line mode applies only to the start and end of string anchors.  The /s flag (which is what allows the . to also match newlines in languages like Perl) isn't supported by javascript.

Comment: @Ender, you're right -- I always just assumed javascript multiline mode meant the same thing as it does in most regex, but a quick test shows it doesn't.

Comment: I had to look it up myself, to be sure :) I found this question that clears it up, if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068280/javascript-regex-multiline-flag-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var result = $(page).find('#start')[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: [This isn't available in all browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t05) - if it were, it wouldn't include the comment.

Answer (score 1):

regex. or the lazy way (which I don't recommend but is quick..) would be to create a hidden DIV, throw it in the div and do a selector for it

```
$('#myNewDiv').next('#start').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

An appropriate [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) will get you what you are looking for.  Try using a line like this:

```
var start = page.match(/(<div id="start">[\s\S]*?<\!-- start -->)/)[1];
```

This uses [JavaScript's match method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) to return an array of matches from your page string, and puts the first parenthetized sub-match (in this case, your #start tag and the following comment), into `start`.

Here's a demo that shows this method working: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/mphUj/