# Underscore.js Templates Within JSP

Tags: jsp, underscore.js

[Underscore.js templates](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) use <%= %> for variable interpolation. Unfortunately that is also interpreted in a JSP (or GSP). Is there a way to use Underscore.js templates within JSPs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the webpage you linked to:

> If ERB-style delimiters aren't your cup of tea, you can change Underscore's template settings >to use different symbols to set off interpolated code.

It suggests you change the `interpolate` and `evaluate` regexes.
This means you can change the <%= %> usage to something that doesn't conflict with JSP.

Comment: Oh jeez, I guess that I had better RTFM! Now don't I feel stupid. ;-) Thanks for the quick response... problem solved.

Answer (score 74):

Add the following interpolate and evaluate settings in your jsp page

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\<\@\=(.+?)\@\>/gim,
    evaluate: /\<\@(.+?)\@\>/gim,
    escape: /\<\@\-(.+?)\@\>/gim
};
```

then you can write your qualify underscore variables,if and for statements with `<@ @>` instead of `<% %>` and will not conflict with jsp

Comment: yes it was answered, but this is for those coders (like me) who would rather have a copy-paste solution :)

Comment: I have added that block in and changed all of my tags to <@ @> and it doesnt seem to be working. Can anyone shed some light on what Im doing wrong?

Comment: @coderman Thank you for understanding the true needs of the average programmer in a hurry

Answer (score 25):

@coderman's example was helpful, but, unfortunately, it doesn't work if you want to use newlines in your templates. For example:

```
   <@ 
      var numPages = 10;
      if ( numPages > 1 ) {
   @>
   <div><@=numPages@></div>
   <@}@>
```

The problem is that the regex for `evaluate` won't match across newlines as described here: [JavaScript regex multiline flag doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068280/javascript-regex-multiline-flag-doesnt-work)

So, the solution that worked for me is:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\<\@\=(.+?)\@\>/gim,
    evaluate: /\<\@([\s\S]+?)\@\>/gim,
    escape: /\<\@\-(.+?)\@\>/gim
};
```

**NOTE**: `[\s\S]` in the evaluate regexp.  That's the key.

Comment: Thanks for this! I have been facing the same problem

Answer (score 5):

The problem can be solved by escaping `<%` sequence in code:

```
<script id="tmpl" type="text/x-template">
    <span>Hello, <\%=name%></span>
</script>
```

So you don't need to change any template engine logics.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that doesn't require global replace is to specify the interpolate and evaluate to specific method invocation

```
 _.template($("#template-id").html(),null, {
   interpolate :  /\{\{\=(.+?)\}\}/g,
   evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
 });`
```