# Rails with Underscore.js Templates

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I was trying to use underscore.js templates for templating in a rails 2.3 app which does **not** have jammit as an asset packager.

Here is the simple Template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="q-template">
    <div class="current-body">
        <span class="q-index"><%= title %></span>
        <span class-"q-text"><%= body %></span>
    </div>
</script>
```

Rails tries to parse these as erb variables and throws an ArgumentError. How do I get underscore templates to play nicely with rails in this case? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use some other delimiters instead of `<%= %>`. For example, to use mustache-style brackets  `{{= }}` (interpolate) and `{{ }}` (evaluate), add this somewhere to your javascript:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{\{\=(.+?)\}\}/g,
    evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was going through the documentation for _.template and _.templateSettings was mentioned there, but somehow it skipped my mind when i was setting up the project, and kept thinking this could be jammit related.

Comment: Thanks FYI : http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771742/underscore-js-templates-within-jsp

Comment: Using `{{ }}` and `{{= }}` can cause problems if you want use `if (x) {}` style blocks in your templates. It's probably easier in that case to use `[% %]` and `[%= %]` instead:

Comment: Another option that doesn't require global replace is to specify the interpolate and evaluate to specific method invocation
`_.template($("#q-template").html(),null, {

           interpolate :  /\{\{\=(.+?)\}\}/g,
           evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
         });`

Answer (score 27):

If you don't want to change the template settings across your entire project...

**Escape the ERB tags**: `<%=` becomes `<%%=`

```
<script type="text/template" id="q-template">
    <div class="current-body">
        <span class="q-index"><%%= title %></span>
        <span class-"q-text"><%%= body %></span>
    </div>
</script>
```

Note that the closing tag is still `%>`, not `%%>`.

---

Side note - I also tried outputting using a heredoc.  The following code runs successfully but outputs a bunch of erb source code that gets caught between the `heredoc` commands.

```
<script type="text/template" id="q-template">
<%= <<-heredoc %>
    <div class="current-body">
        <span class="q-index"><%%= title %></span>
        <span class-"q-text"><%%= body %></span>
    </div>
heredoc
</script>
```