# what is the use of <%% in underscore templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

can some one tell me difference between "<%%" "<%"

```
<%%= hello %>

<%= hello %>
```

i could not find proper answer in google search.

Any explanations will be helpful :)

```
**Index.html**

<div id="container">Loading...</div>
<script type="script/template" id="hello_sen">
<%= hello %>
</script>

**Backbone View**

class Bckbone.Views.EntriesIndex extends Backbone.View

initialize: ->
    @template = _.template($("#hello_sen").html())

render: ->
    datas = {hello: "Senthil"}
    $(@el).html(@template(datas))
    this
```

Comment: While you can change the [delimiters in underscore by declaring an interpolate regex](http://underscorejs.org/#template) that looks like it's a typo to me.

Comment: No Steveax , its not typo. Please check this screenshot : http://awesomescreenshot.com/06dqqsq78 , if i am writing "<%" , it throws me variable not found error, same if i am writing "<%%"  , I ma getting correct results. (I seen "<%%" in some others projects)

Comment: Has anything changed the Underscore template settings? Is something on the server preprocessing the templates before Underscore sees them? And how says "variable not found"? The client or the server?

Comment: Variable not found is error from Server . I think server seeing templates before underscore. I am adding my codes for clear picture.

Comment: Why are you sending your Underscore templates through ERB?

Comment: I am very new to underscore , I am not sure about this. If you can say me which is right place (for saving/serving template), it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error in the screenshot you posted above because you're using `erb` style underscore template (the default) inside an `erb` file.

The code inside `<%` and `%>` is being parsed as Ruby code.

You should use alternate interpolation strings, as described [here](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template).

Answer (score 0):

Backbone.js relies on underscore.js for templating. <% is convention in underscore. <%% escapes the ERB tags for rails.  You can change underscore's settings:

```
 _.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{\{\=(.+?)\}\}/g,
    evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

Or use <%% to escape on a line by line basis. Escaping still ends with %>

More here: [Rails with Underscore.js Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514922/rails-with-underscore-js-templates)

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution: Move the template to a partial, and don't include the .erb after .html in the filename. Then rails won't parse ERB in that file.