# How do I use ejs templates in conjunction with underscore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, underscore.js, ejs

In underscore, <%- stuff %> escapes HTML.

However, in EJS, <%= stuff %> escapes HTML.

If there was a way to make this consistent, life would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can make EJS work like Underscore here, but you can do the converse - see [Rails with Underscore.js Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514922/rails-with-underscore-js-templates) for inspiration.

Comment: I don't care which I change. I just want them to be consistent.