# convert this php regex to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, regex, converters

I'm wondering how to change this exact php regex feature into javascript?

```
$ismatch= preg_match('|She is a <span><b>(.*)</b></span>|si', $sentence, $matchresult);

if($ismatch)
{
      $gender= $matchresult[1];
}
else{ //do other thing }
```

Comment: Bad news, JS doesn't support the dotall switch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068280/javascript-regex-multiline-flag-doesnt-work

Comment: This could be a good question if phrased properly and the focus was on the dotall modifier... in its current state it sounds like a "Do the work for me" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not quite trivial since JavaScript doesn't support the `s` modifier.

The equivalent regex object would be

```
/She is a <span><b>([\s\S]*)<\/b><\/span>/i
```

The functionality of the code (extracting group 1 from the match if there is a match) would be done in JavaScript like this:

```
var myregexp = /She is a <span><b>([\s\S]*)<\/b><\/span>/i;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
} else {
    // do other thing
}
```

Comment: Information about the `[\s\S]` approach can be found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp): *(The decimal point) matches any single character except the newline characters: `\n` `\r` `\u2028` or `\u2029`. (`[\s\S]` can be used to match any character including newlines.)*

Comment: Or use the special JS feature `[^]`, it matches any character.

Comment: @Qtax: Wow, I'd never seen this before. Is there any documentation about this?

Comment: @Tim, don't know, haven't seen it documented, but haven't really looked for it either. Unlike Perl/PCRE in JS the first unescaped `]` seems to end the character class without exceptions, thus `[^]` would match everything except nothing, i.e everything.