# Why Doesn't This Regexp work?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the regexp: `/<\?nib.+\?>/im`

I'm testing it on a file like this:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>OPEN LARK</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>THIS IS A HEADER 

    <?nib   
             asdf
    ?>
</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

I am getting no matches. How can I fix this?

Comment: @p.s.w.g: be careful, because m in ruby is like s in other regex flavors, but in javascript m means line by line mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the `.` to match multilines. That isn't implemented in Javascript. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1068308/2517733) for a workaround.

**About the workaround:**

Instead of the dot, use a class and its negation to match everything. For example, replace the `.` with `[\s\S]`.

Answer (score 4):

because the dot (`.`) doesn't match newlines.

The way in javascript is to replace the dot by `[\s\S]`