# To the last tag (already in a string) RegEx

Tags: javascript, xml, regex

I do not know what I am doing wrong. I have this string that I want to replace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <Sections>
  <Section>
```

I am using regex to replace everything including `<Section>`, and leave the rest untouched.

```
arrayValues[index].replace("/[([.,\n,\s])*<Section>]/", "---");
```

What is wrong with my regex? Doesn't this mean repalce every character, including new line and spaces, up to and including `<Section>` with `---`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Tony? Tony? ... Tony?

Comment: @kristian http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182189/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant, besides, regex CAN parse html just fine, despite popular belief.

Comment: I understand that regex can't be use with tags, but I already made the XML doc into a string. I also check using typeOf on arrayValues[index] to make sure that they are a string.

Comment: You should be processing this using [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), not regex. You are collapsing all whitespace, which is creating this: `<?xml---version="1.0"---encoding="utf-8"---?>------<Sections>---------`..etc

Comment: @Kristian You'd be better of linking to that answer, I've seen people think the Q is different so the answer doesn't apply...

Comment: Well I am uploading the XML doc on the client side using a reader and is using readAsText so it is returning me a string.

Comment: @JackThor The problem isn't that it can't be used with tags - all html/xml docs with tags are just specially formatted strings - the problem is that the layout and formatting of those tags in the string has meaning more complex than a regex can cope with (at least, unless you're talking about thousands of characters in your regex). It's just the wrong tool for the job

Comment: regex is a **perfectly fine** tool for this job. he's got a bit of text, and wants to replace some of it. regex will work perfectly well for this; in fact, that's what it's designed to do.

Comment: @sgroves, regexs can help *lex* HTML but they can't be used to correctly *parse* HTML,  because [whether `<![CDATA[` starts a CDATA section](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#cdata-sections) depends on whether you are in a foreign XML context and determining that requires matching end tags with start tags which is not doable solely with regular expressions, not even when extended with back-references.  Yes, you can hack something together to solve a particular problem on a subset of HTML, but that's not the same as parsing HTML.

Comment: @MikeSamuel correct, i technically meant lex not parse. the vast majority of regex/html questions here talk about lexing, and 99% of the time someone links to that cthulu post it's entirely inapplicable to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to remove the quotes around your regex—if they're there, the argument won't be processed as a regex. JavaScript will see it as a string (because it is a string) and try to match it literally.

Now that that's taken care of, we can simplify your regex a bit:

```
arrayValues[index].replace(/[\s\S]*?<Section>/, "---");
```

---

`[\s\S]` gets around JavaScript's lack of an `s` flag (a handy option supported by most languages that enables `.` to match newlines). `\s` *does* match newlines (even without an `s` flag specified), so the character class `[\s\S]` tells the regex engine to match:

- `\s` - a whitespace character, which could be a newline

**OR**

- `\S` - a **non**-whitespace character

So you can think of `[\s\S]` as matching `.` (any character except a newline) or the literal `\n` (a newline). See [Javascript regex multiline flag doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068280/javascript-regex-multiline-flag-doesnt-work) for more.

---

`?` is used to make the initial `[\s\S]*` match non-greedy, so the regex engine will stop once it hits the first occurrence of `<Section>`.

Comment: I'd make the class non-greedy, just in case.

Comment: reading the answer posted on the link trying to wrap my head around the [\s\S]. How does this match a new line? Maybe I should post this as a different quesiton.

Comment: @JackThor short answer: because `\s` will match a newline (whereas `.` will not). see my updated answer for more.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> arrayValues[index].replace("/[([.,\n,\s])*<Section>]/", "---");
> ```
>
> What is wrong with my regex?

It's no regex, it's string literal. A string would be converted to a regex, but yours would then include the slashes. Use a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression) instead:

```js
arrayValues[index].replace(/[\S\s]*<Section>/, "---");
```

Also, you have too many unnecessary characters in it. The `[]` around the whole thing build a character class, which is not what you want. The capturing group `()` just wraps a character class which can be repeated itself. And a dot `.` inside a character class does match a literal dot, instead of all characters.