# How to replace particular string from a multiline textarea using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, multiline

When i have string which consists of a single line, replace works just fine.

As soon as i type in some text into text area and press enter as for new line, replace won't work anymore.

```
var currentValue = $('#service-field').val();
$('#service-field').val(currentValue.replace("particular string",""));
```

What should I do?

Comment: you should take into account that the string might have a linebreak in it.

Comment: yep, you might also be interested by this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068280/javascript-regex-multiline-flag-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to make sure you capture all occurrences, and not just the ones on the first line:

```
$('#service-field').val(currentValue.replace(/particular string/g, ""));
```

Or with a variable:

```
var t = "particular string";
$('#service-field').val(currentValue.replace(eval("/" + t + "/g"), ""));
```

Comment: Any way to pass "particular string as a variable this way?

Comment: Now I'm getting error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /".

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis or quotation mark most likely. The above works for me.