# regex to match section of string between two constants with new line in the center

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have a block of text in the following format:

```
FARE CALC INDICATOR: 9 
PHL US CUN264.00AA MIA102.00AA PHL88.37NUC454.37END ROE1.00 US 
XT34.40US5.00XA5.00AY 23.20UK28.14XD9.00XFPHL4.5 MIA4.5

               **FARE BREAKDOWN/FOP/TOUR CODE**
```

Using Javascript and regex, I need to match this section:

**PHL US CUN264.00AA MIA102.00AA PHL88.37NUC454.37END ROE1.00 US 
    XT34.40US5.00XA5.00AY 23.20UK28.14XD9.00XFPHL4.5 MIA4.5**

Basically I need to find the next line break after `FARE CALC INDICATOR:` and return all the text between that point and `**FARE BREAKDOWN/FOP/TOUR CODE**`

I tried `.match(/FARE CALC INDICATOR:([\s\S]+)\*\*FARE BREAKDOWN\/FOP\/TOUR CODE\*\*/)`

This almost works but, if there is any text between `FARE CALC INDICATOR:` and the next new line (like the number `9` in this example) that text gets captured also and should not.

The number `9` in this example could potentially be any character and is not limited to one character

Comment: As there seems to be no `dotall` flag in javascript see the workarounds given in http://stackoverflow.com/q/1068280/2870069

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As dot `.` doesn't match newline, you could do:

```
.match(/FARE CALC INDICATOR:.*([\s\S]+)\*\*FARE BREAKDOWN\/FOP\/TOUR CODE\*\*/)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
/FARE CALC INDICATOR:[^\r\n]*\r?\n\s*([\s\S]+?)\s+\*\*FARE BREAKDOWN\/FOP\/TOUR CODE\*\*/
```

the capture group begin at the next newline after `FARE CALC INDICATOR:` and stop before the last newline after the content.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need any fancy regex for this. Consider this code:

```
str = "FARE CALC INDICATOR: 9 \n" + 
"PHL US CUN264.00AA MIA102.00AA PHL88.37NUC454.37END ROE1.00 US \n" + 
"XT34.40US5.00XA5.00AY 23.20UK28.14XD9.00XFPHL4.5 MIA4.5\n" + 
"\n" + 
"               **FARE BREAKDOWN/FOP/TOUR CODE**\n";

var p1 = 'FARE CALC INDICATOR: 9'; // start pattern
var p2 = '**FARE BREAKDOWN/FOP/TOUR CODE**'; // end pattern

var i1 = str.indexOf( p1 );
var i2 = str.indexOf( p2 );
// TODO: check if i1 and i2 are > 0 here

var substr = str.substring(i1 + p1.length + 1, i2 - 1);

console.log( substr );
// PHL US CUN264.00AA MIA102.00AA PHL88.37NUC454.37END ROE1.00 US 
// XT34.40US5.00XA5.00AY 23.20UK28.14XD9.00XFPHL4.5 MIA4.5
```

Comment: With this example yes but, "The number 9 in this example could potentially be any character and is not limited to one character" Is the reason Im going with regex

Comment: Actually you could have replaced p1 and p2 with any other string and it would work fine.

Comment: True, but Im going to be parsing 1,000s of blocks like this and the characters that come after ":" are generated in many different unpredictable patterns. Well, at least not easily predictable. But thank you though I do see the merit of this solution otherwise.