# Change everything in between two text/strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to replace everything in between `[lorem]` and `[/lorem]`. For example:

`[lorem]Here goes some text[/lorem]`

will turn into

`These is inside a lorem block`

I've manged to make it work with `[[Here goes some text]]`, using

```
var block = $('body').html().replace(/\[[^\]]+\]]/ig, "This is inside a lorem block");
$('body').html(block);
```

but I can't, for the life of me, make it work using the former, either because I'm doing something wrong or I don't actually understand how that works. Also, what does `^` in the replace function do? I'm guessing it means something like "anything in between" but of course I could be wrong. Where can I read about those?

Comment: try wrapping the text you want to replace in a span tag

Comment: Yeah, the thing is I need to use the `[lorem][/lorem]`

Comment: `replace(/\[lorem\].*?\[\/lorem\]/ig, 'This is inside a lorem block');`?

Comment: try this `[lorem]<span class="_1">Here goes some text</span>[/lorem]` then just replace the text using the span class `._1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the RegExp `/\[lorem\].*?\[\/lorem\]/ig`:

```
var block = $('body').html().replace(/\[lorem\].*?\[\/lorem\]/ig, "This is inside a lorem block");
$('body').html(block);
```

### EDIT:

To allow for newline characters use the following: (credit to @PatrickAllen)

```
var block = $('body').html().replace(/\[lorem\][\s\S]*?\[\/lorem\]/ig, "This is inside a lorem block");
$('body').html(block);
```

Comment: Ah that's great, it works! Quick question, what if there's a line break inside the `[lorem][/lorem]`? This works great when it's in a single line but for some reason it stops when I put breaks.

Comment: Would adding the `m` flag help?

Comment: use `[\s\S]` instead of a `.`  There is no m flag in JS.  So use this: `/\[lorem\][\s\S]*?\[\/lorem\]/ig`

Comment: Ah yes, Just found out about [\s\S] from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068280 right before this and it works now. The `m` flag doesn't work as @PatrickAllen said. Thanks, you guys!

Comment: @PatrickAllen There is an `m` flag, just thinking about a different functionality.