# Match only the inner HTML?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a templating engine and I have a syntax that looks like this:

```
{{If "{{Line}}" != ""}}
    {{If "{{Line}}" != ""}}
        <li id="{{Required:Id}}" class="menuEntry line">
    {{EndIf}}
    <li id="{{Required:Id}}" class="menuEntry line">
{{EndIf}}
```

Now, I'm searching for a regex to get my if statements, meaning from `{{If` until `{{EndIf}}` everything in between should be included.

I came up with the regex:

```
/({{If)[.]*?[\s\S]*?({{EndIf}})/g
```

And this does work fine when I have only 1 if statement, but with nested if statements, it goes wrong.

The above regex would give me:

```
{{If "{{Line}}" != ""}}
    {{If "{{Line}}" != ""}}
    <li id="{{Required:Id}}" class="menuEntry line">
   {{EndIf}}
```

And in fact I'm expecting to retrieve:

```
    {{If "{{Line}}" != ""}}
    <li id="{{Required:Id}}" class="menuEntry line">
   {{EndIf}}
```

Anyone who can provide me some guidance here?

Comment: Are you able to not use regex to parse the HTML? If so, I'd go with a parsing library. What language are you implementing this template engine in?

Comment: It's not possible for me to do this I'm affraid. I'm using JavaScript for this templating engine. The id is to render complex HTML from this using my engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.*?` that matches everything (including `{{If`) you can use a negative lookahead matching everything except `{{If` like this: `(?!.*{{If)`.

Your regex than becomes (you can [test it here](http://regex101.com/r/fL2wR2/1)):

```
/{{If(?!.*{{If).*?{{EndIf}}/gs
```

Since Javascript does not have the *dotall* modifier `s` to allow dot to match also newlines, you can use a class and its negation instead of the `.` (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068280/javascript-regex-multiline-flag-doesnt-work)). Then you regex becomes (test it [here](http://regex101.com/r/kA9nN9/1)):

```
/{{If(?![\s\S]*?{{If)[\s\S]*?{{EndIf}}/g
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(\{\{If)((?:(?!\{\{If \"\{\{Line\}\}\" \!= \"\"\}\}|\{\{EndIf\}\}).)*)?(\{\{EndIf\}\})/sg
```

try this might help you

Comment: Explain, please. It's too long and complicated to decode. Hint: In regex, you can use the `x` flag to make your regex `extended`. This allows you to place comment blocks within the regex itself, and split it along multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can try:

```
}}\s+({{If [\s\S]*?{{EndIf}})
```

Get the matched group from index 1

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sL4dH5/3)

Here is the code:

```
var myString = '...';
var myRegexp = /}}\s*({{If [\s\S]*?{{EndIf}})/gi;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, the '}}' from the previous statement are also part of found data, isn't it?

Comment: Get the matched group only that is enclosed inside the parenthesis `(...)` from index 1. for code see Code generator link in the demo.

Comment: But in light blue, the 2 }} are ale taken into account. I don't get it.

Comment: Just tested it and it includes it :-)