# Replace all characters including whitespace in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following string , `s1` , as a part of a longer text (which doesn't have the following patter in it i.e. this pattern only happens once through out the text. The text also includes white spaces and new lines)

```
<!-- COMPONENTS_LIST_START -->
* [line-vis](line-chart)
* [trend-vis](trend-vis)
<!-- COMPONENTS_LIST_END -->
```

I want to replace it with the following string , `s2` :

```
<!-- COMPONENTS_LIST_START -->
* [line-vis](line-chart)
* [trend-vis](trend-vis)
* [common-vis](common-vis)
<!-- COMPONENTS_LIST_END -->
```

I use the following RegEx but it doesn't match it :

```
str1.replace(/<!-- COMPONENTS_LIST_START -->(\s|.)*<!-- COMPONENTS_LIST_END -->/, str2)
```

Doesn't this : `(\s|.)*` mean , all characters including white space characters ?

Comment: You are looking for the /.../s modifier

Comment: Could you please explain more ?

Comment: Also, you probably need the non-greedy quantifier (`*?`) if your string might have multiple components lists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068280/javascript-regex-multiline-flag-doesnt-work

Comment: Just edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a greedy regex so you will mess things. Btw, you can use `[\S\s]` ungreedy instead like this:

```
str1.replace(/<!-- COMPONENTS_LIST_START -->[\S\s]*?<!-- COMPONENTS_LIST_END -->/, str2)
```

The idea behind `[\S\s]*?` is to match everything until the first occurrence of your pattern, in your case `<!-- COMPONENTS_LIST_END -->`

And also as Trott pointed in his answer, assign the string a result:

```
str1 = str1.replace(/<!-- COMPONENTS_LIST_START -->[\S\s]*?<!-- COMPONENTS_LIST_END -->/, str2);
```

Comment: "this pattern only happens once through out the text" so making it non-greedy will only improve performance, not make it "more correct". Also [\S\s] should be written as [^] (the negation of nothing).

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression works. The problem you are experiencing is that `.replace()` does not mutate the string. It returns a new string. If you want it to mutate the string, you need to assign the return value.

```
str1 = str1.replace(/<!-- COMPONENTS_LIST_START -->(\s|.)*<!-- COMPONENTS_LIST_END -->/, str2);
```

Comment: Actually, OP regex is greedy so technically isn't working, you are using mine :)

Comment: Oh shoot, I accidentally copy/pasted the regexp from your answer thinking I was copy/pasting from his question! Will edit...

Comment: No worries at all, just wanted to let you know that OP regex wasn't working

Comment: His works, but it replaces the entire string rather than just the inner part. But it appears that's what he wants/expects. Yours is better, though. Leaves the common prefix/suffix intact and all that.