# Matching strings in multiline text

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
var str = "something\n
// comment\n
somethingElse();\n
end();\n";
```

I have to remove from it the commend and everything below it. How can I do that? I tried:

```
str.replace(/(\/\/.*?end\(\);)/s, '');
```

But I am getting an error that the `/s` flag is undefined. What's wrong?

Comment: The `/s` flag is undefined :) I think you need `/m` for do multiline (I edited 3 times to find the correct flag out of 4 possible flags)

Comment: Check the MDN documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068280/javascript-regex-multiline-flag-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replace(/\/\/.*\\n\r?\n/, "");
```

Matches two `//` + whatever followed by `\n` and a unix or windows line-return.

**EDIT** I think I misread your question. To remove your comment *and everything below it* you can use

```
str.replace(/(\r?\n)\/\/[\s\S]*/, "$1");
```

but make sure the `//` start a new line.