# How do I use regex modifiers in jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this html content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center><img style="margin-left: auto; display: block; margin-right: auto;" src="../img/escudocaba.png" alt="#" width="470" height="90" /></center>
<h1>Hoddda</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to extract the content of the body without including the body tags. I have made this regex that match perfectly:

```
/<body[^>]*>(.*?)<\/body>/is
```

as you can see in this website

https://regex101.com/

But when I use it

```
var bodyHtml=$editor.val().match( /<body[^>]*>(.*?)<\/body>/is);
```

I get no results.......Also tried a similar regex which did not work out in the end with the same format and without modifiers and it was matching

```
   var bodyHtml=$editor.val().match(/(?:.(?!<\s*body[^>]*>))*\>.+/);
```

for example returned

```
<center><img style="margin-left: auto; display: block; margin-right: auto;" src="../img/escudocaba.png" alt="#" width="470" height="90" /></center>
```

How can I do in this case to use regex modifiers with this jquery function?. Thanks

Comment: You can simply do : $('body').html() to get the contents of the body without the body tag

Comment: Is that... is that a `center` tag? What year is it?!?

Comment: Oh yeah, and this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1232175, just use `$('body').html();` as Dino suggested.

Comment: that's no good...I need the body of the editor canvas, not the body of the whole page

Comment: The html structure I was talking(the one which is inside a textarea with id="#plantillaEditor") about is inside the main html of the whole page......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript flavour of regex the `.` doesn't match new lines.

To solve that you can use `[^]` or `[\s\S]` or `[\d\D]` or `(?:.|\n)` ...

Try this code:

```
var bodyHtml = $editor.val().match(/<body[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)(<\/body>|$)/i)[1];
```

Comment: this doesn't work, it returns "undifined"

Comment: @JAF. I suspect just `$editor.find('body').html()` should work

Comment: It's not working my friend.....If I put

console.log(($('textarea').val()));

I get

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center><img style="margin-left: auto; display: block; margin-right: auto;" src="../img/escudocaba.png" alt="#" width="470" height="90" /></center>
<h1>Hodddaaa</h1>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @JAF. Last try: `$($editor.val()).find('body').html()`. Otherwise, just change the `.` in the regex by one of the options I said in my answer.

Comment: That didn't work, I already tried that. Regarding replacing the point, what are you refering to?...what would be the final expression?

Comment: @JAF. I saw the problem now... when you try to create the string as DOM it loads everything including the images' source... I would persist on regex and maybe use `/<body[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)(<\/body>|$)/`

Comment: almost....if I use that regex the result is

<body>
<center><img style="margin-left: auto; display: block; margin-right: auto;" src="../img/escudocaba.png" alt="#" width="470" height="90" /></center>
<h1>Hodddaaa</h1>
</body>

I need the text without the body tags

Comment: @JAF. I've updated my answer

Comment: this is the correct answer, thank you very much my friend

Answer (score 0):

The s-modifier doesn't exist in JS. try using [\s\S] instead of the dot, as suggested here: [Javascript regex multiline flag doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068280/javascript-regex-multiline-flag-doesnt-work)

like this:

```
<body[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/body>
```

Comment: This regex will fail if the HTML doc is long and there is no closing `</body>`.