# Get content with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
::head
line 1
line 2
line 3

::content
content 1
content 2
content 3
```

How do I get "head" paragraph(first part) text with regex? This is from txt file.

Comment: `indexOf` and `substring`

Comment: What have you tried? As it is, you could easily do this without regex by just breaking on the empty line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the below doesn't work in javascript because of this: [Javascript regex multiline flag doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068280/javascript-regex-multiline-flag-doesnt-work).  So we have to tweak things a bit.  A line break in a file can be found in javascript strings as `\n`.  In windows this includes `\r` but not in linux, so our `\s*` becomes **more** important now that we're doing this without using line-ending characters (`$`).  I also noticed that you don't need to specifically gather the other lines, since line breaks are being ignored anyway.

```
/(::head[^]*?)\n\s*\n/m
```

This works in testing in Chrome, so it should work for your needs.

---

this is a little fancy, but it should fit if this is used in conjunction with many similar properties.

```
/(::head.*?$^.*?$)^\s*$/m
```

Note that you need the `/m` multiline flag.

Here it is tested against your sample data http://rubular.com/r/vtflEgDdkY

First, we check for the `::head` data.  That's where we start collecting information in a group with `()`.  Then we look for anything with `.*`, but we do so with the lazy `?` flag.  Then we find the end of the line with `$` and look for more lines with data with the line start `^` then anything `.*?` then the line end `$` this will grab multiple lines because of the multiline flag, so it's important to use the lazy matching `?` so we don't grab too much data.  Then we look for an empty line.  Normally you just need `^$` for that, but I wanted to make sure this would work if someone had stuck a stray space or tab on the lines in between sections, so we used `\s*` to grab spaces. The `*` allows it to find "0 or more" spaces as acceptable.  Notice we didn't include the empty line in the group `()` because that's not the data you care about.

For further reading on regex, I recommend http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html  It's where I learned everything I know about regex.

Comment: I have to use javascript... Thank for reply

Comment: javascript uses regex natively.  You want an entire app or the regular expression?

Comment: Hi again, it didnt work in JS. It returns null.. code: `var file = readTextFile("deneme.txt");
var result = file.match(/(::head.*?$^.*?$)^\s*$/m);`

Comment: it appears to be a wierd caveat of js regex, looking into it right now.

Comment: an alternative with `\n` instead of `$^` is here http://regexr.com/3djad but I'm not seeing it work in testing either

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[\s\S]+::content` to match everything *until* `::content`:

```
const text = ...
const matches = text.match(/^([\s\S]+)::content/m)
const content = matches[1]
```

Comment: @user3791836 You wrote `::head` instead of `::content`

Comment: @user3791836 You can make it lazy like this: `/^([\s\S]+?)::content/m` (https://regex101.com/r/pH4xS2/3). Updated my answer with code.