# RegEx for matching text between two tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this text

```
Donec ante sapien, gravida id risus eget,
<exclude>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis neque ex. Aenean ac leo quis ex lobortis aliquam. Donec libero dolor, sodales in molestie vel, sagittis at nulla. Proin egestas dolor turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc eget enim varius, condimentum tortor sit amet, aliquet magna. Phasellus ut libero quis diam dignissim interdum. Sed commodo iaculis vestibulum. Quisque viverra diam sed orci rhoncus luctus. Mauris leo mauris, consequat at lacinia sit amet, viverra vitae enim. Donec maximus, ipsum in bibendum volutpat, est erat dapibus leo, et iaculis arcu augue in dolor.
<exclude>
Donec ante sapien, gravida id risus eget,
```

I want to get the text between `<exclude>` tags, I have this express but it does not work for me : `/\<exclude\>/g`

#### Note:

The tag could anything even something like `#x` it is just a delimiter to the that portion of the text.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/85615

Comment: Is it correct that both of those tags are `<exclude>` rather than `<exclude>` and `</exclude>`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job:

```
<exclude>((?:[^<]|<(?!exclude>))*)(?=<exclude>)
^---1---^|^----------2----------^|^-----3-----^
         +-----------4-----------+
```

This specifies the following:

1. Match the characters `<exclude>`.
2. Accept all characters that are **not** `<` **or** `<` not followed by `exclude>`.
3. The match may only end if it is followed by the characters `<exclude>`.
4. Capture the characters between the two tags in group 1.

For something simpler like the tag `#x` you can use the same principal:

```
#x((?:[^#]|#(?!x))*)(?=#x)
```

```js
var text = `
Donec ante sapien, gravida id risus eget,
<exclude>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis neque ex. Aenean ac leo quis ex lobortis aliquam. Donec libero dolor, sodales in molestie vel, sagittis at nulla. Proin egestas dolor turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc eget enim varius, condimentum tortor sit amet, aliquet magna. Phasellus ut libero quis diam dignissim interdum. Sed commodo iaculis vestibulum. Quisque viverra diam sed orci rhoncus luctus. Mauris leo mauris, consequat at lacinia sit amet, viverra vitae enim. Donec maximus, ipsum in bibendum volutpat, est erat dapibus leo, et iaculis arcu augue in dolor.
<exclude>
Donec ante sapien, gravida id risus eget,
`.trim();

var regex = /<exclude>((?:[^<]|<(?!exclude>))*)(?=<exclude>)/g;

while (match = regex.exec(text)) {
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: You could change `(?=<exclude>)` to simply `<exclude>`. This has the following effect: `<exclude>1<exclude>2<exclude>3<exclude>` would match `1`, `2` and `3`. Making this change would let it match `1` and `3`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is correct and this isn't actually XML (for which you should use an XML parser instead). Given you specific example, this would work:

```js
var str = `Donec ante sapien, gravida id risus eget,
<exclude>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis neque ex. Aenean ac leo quis ex lobortis aliquam. Donec libero dolor, sodales in molestie vel, sagittis at nulla. Proin egestas dolor turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc eget enim varius, condimentum tortor sit amet, aliquet magna. Phasellus ut libero quis diam dignissim interdum. Sed commodo iaculis vestibulum. Quisque viverra diam sed orci rhoncus luctus. Mauris leo mauris, consequat at lacinia sit amet, viverra vitae enim. Donec maximus, ipsum in bibendum volutpat, est erat dapibus leo, et iaculis arcu augue in dolor.
<exclude>
Donec ante sapien, gravida id risus eget,`;

console.log(/<exclude>(.*?)<exclude>/gs.exec(str)[1]);
```

Your are going to look for something that matches `<exclude>` then we are going to group everything up to the next `<exclude>`. Although it makes no difference to *this* example, we use a lazy quantifier so if there are multiple pairs of `<exclude>` tags, you only match up to the *next* `<exclude>` and not the last `<exclude>`.

Comment: When was the `s` flag added? I get the error *"SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag s"*.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1068308/1250301

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 
"Donec ante sapien, gravida id risus eget,\n" +
"<exclude>\n" +
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis neque ex. Aenean ac leo quis ex lobortis aliquam. Donec libero dolor, sodales in molestie vel, sagittis at nulla. Proin egestas dolor turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc eget enim varius, condimentum tortor sit amet, aliquet magna. Phasellus ut libero quis diam dignissim interdum. Sed commodo iaculis vestibulum. Quisque viverra diam sed orci rhoncus luctus. Mauris leo mauris, consequat at lacinia sit amet, viverra vitae enim. Donec maximus, ipsum in bibendum volutpat, est erat dapibus leo, et iaculis arcu augue in dolor.\n" +
"<exclude>\n" +
"Donec ante sapien, gravida id risus eget,\n"

var regex = /<exclude>([\S\s]*?)<exclude>/g;
var found = regex.exec( str )[1];

console.log( found );
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to design an expression for such output is to use capturing groups that most of answers are already using that.

Also, you can add other flags such as multiline or single line (depending on your input string) to your expression, as you wish. [This tool](https://regex101.com/r/S0e5VB/1/) might help you to do so, design and test your expressions and see how they work:

[image]

#### RegEx

```
(.*)(<exclude>)(.+)(<exclude>)(.*)
```

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work:

[image]

#### Performance

This JavaScript snippet shows the performance of this expression using a simple 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
repeat = 1000000;
start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 var string = "Donec ante sapien, gravida id risus eget,\n" +
  "<exclude>\n" +
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis neque ex. Aenean ac leo quis ex lobortis aliquam. Donec libero dolor, sodales in molestie vel, sagittis at nulla. Proin egestas dolor turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc eget enim varius, condimentum tortor sit amet, aliquet magna. Phasellus ut libero quis diam dignissim interdum. Sed commodo iaculis vestibulum. Quisque viverra diam sed orci rhoncus luctus. Mauris leo mauris, consequat at lacinia sit amet, viverra vitae enim. Donec maximus, ipsum in bibendum volutpat, est erat dapibus leo, et iaculis arcu augue in dolor.\n" +
  "<exclude>\n" +
  "Donec ante sapien, gravida id risus eget,\n";
 var regex = /(.+)(<exclude>)(.+)(<exclude>)(.+)/gms;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$3");
}

end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```